# Vue.js - Get N element from array - Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have some issues with my Vue.JS code. I need to get 5-th element of my array and it's work fine but Vue display also a couple of errors

To get my data I used this code:

```
<div>
  <span>{{ items[4].name }}</span>
</div>
```

It's work fine (Vue display data) but I have also this error in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.items[4] is undefined"

found in

---> <GeneralComponent> at resources/js/components/GeneralComponent.vue
       <General> at resources/js/views/General.vue
         <App> at resources/js/views/App.vue
           <Root>


TypeError: "_vm.items[4] is undefined"
```

Comment: did you checked your array length ? does it contains 5 element or less ?

Comment: Can you post more of the code you are using? What does the `data` object look like?... need some more code to help..

Comment: are you loading the data via an api or something? You must ensure that `items` and `items[4]` is actually available before referencing `name` - e.g. `<span v-if="items && items[4]">{{ items[4].name }}</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your array is populated after it is accessed in your dom, so you can try it like this:

```
{{ items[4] && items[4].name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get element before it rendered so I will say first check the length

```
<div v-if='items.lenght>0'>
   <span>{{ items[4].name }}</span>
</div>
```